# Vim: split line at the end of 4 random number sequences

Tags: regex, vim, full-text-search

I have a text file that is all contained in one line.

e.g.

```
Scheme 4078 6291 4205 66 Video 23522 4323 53522 4233 Social 23 5432 6 54
```

I would like to split it up into lines that keep the name and its four assocated numbers on one line.

hence:

```
Scheme 4078 6291 4205 66

Video 23522 4323 53522 4233 

Social 23 5432 6 54
```

I've been trying things like

```
/[[:digit:]]+ [[:digit:]]+ [[:digit:]]+ [[:digit:]]+
```

And I figure that it must go into a line that involves :%s but I'm getting lost. 
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way. It doesn't look at four digit groups, but to any word with no digits and inserts a newline character in front of it.

```
:%s/\v\s+(\D+)/\r\1/g
```

It yields:

```
Scheme 4078 6291 4205 66
Video 23522 4323 53522 4233
Social 23 5432 6 54
```

Comment: Thank you! This deals with the few cases of multiple words in a row too which is great and something that I missed from my question. @JohnSmith's answer works as well.

Answer (score 1):

This substitution should work.

```
:%s/\s\+\(\D\)/\r\1/g
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works with the similar syntax you used

```
:%s/\(\(\<[[:digit:]]\+\>[ \t]\+\)\{4\}\)/\1\r/g
```

Answer (score 0):

If these are the only keywords then this will work

```
:%s/\(Scheme\|Video\|Social\)/\r\1/g
```